# find lowest value in nested array in javascript

Tags: javascript

i am trying to find the name with the lowest number after it, but iterating over it is slow with larger lists. For exaple the expected output should be ["bob", 1]
["jeff", 2]
["wal-E",2]

```js
let items = [["bob",1],["jeff",2],["wal-E",2],["bob",1],["bob",10]]
let items2 = []
let Lowest = 0;
for (y in items){
    for (z in items)
      {
        if (items[y][0] == items[z][0] && items[y][1]<=items[z][1]){
          continue;
        } else if (items[y][0] == items[z][0]){
            Lowest += 1
            if (Lowest >= 2){
            break;
            }
            else {
            continue;
            }
        }
        }      
  if (Lowest == 0){
    items2.push(items[y])
  }
}
console.log(items2);
```

Comment: do you have only a single lowest value with same name? do you want only the name?

Comment: @NinaScholz i want the lowest value for each name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could reduce the array and collect the smallest values.

```js
const
    items = [["bob", 1], ["jeff", 2], ["wal-E", 2], ["bob", 1], ["bob", 10]],
    result = Object.entries(items.reduce((r, [name, value]) => {
        if (!(name in r) || r[name] > value) r[name] = value;
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thanks this works, would there be a way to get the second-lowest value for each name?

Comment: you could collect all values instead of using the min value and map later only the wanted values.

Answer (score 4):

Using `reduce` is an elegant solution to acheive this

```js
let items = [["bob",1],["jeff",2],["wal-E",2],["bob",1],["bob",10]];

const lowestItem = items.reduce((a, b) => a[1] < b[1] ? a : b);

console.log(lowestItem);
```

Read more about `Array.prototype.reduce` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: i want the lowest value for each name, this gives the lowest value total

Answer (score 0):

You can store the name with the lowest number and the lowest number in two seperate variables, then loop through the array and check whether each array's second item is smaller than the lowest number.

If so, set the lowest number to the second item in the array and the lowest name to the first item in the array.

```js
let items = [["bob",1],["jeff",2],["wal-E",2],["bob",1],["bob",10]]
let lowest;
let lowestName;

items.forEach(e => {
  if(!lowest || e[1] < lowest){
    lowest = e[1];
    lowestName = e[0];
  }
})

console.log(lowestName, lowest)
```